# How to get results from multiple tables using a single query in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pdo

I have a situation where i need to get data from 7 different tables for a particular processing to be performed.

I will need 7 simple `SELECT` all statements, nothing fancy. But to minimize the database hit, I will very much like to bundle these queries into 1 or 2 queries.

Like:

```
select * from table1; select * from table2; select * from table3;.
```

And will call this query from my code. Is is possible to get the results in something on the similar lines of .net's DataSet in PHP. I am looking for a solution in core PHP or CodeIgniter. I am using PDO for database connection.

PS: The tables have different schemas, no common point. So any solution with join or union will not work.

```
$results = $this->db-query("select * from tb1; select * from tb2");
```

now `$result[0]` should have all the records from tb1 and `$results[1]` should have the records from tb2.

Something on the similar line will be most helpful in this scenario.

Comment: You have provided no table structure nor actual code. Update your question please. p.s It's CodeIgnitEr not CodeIgnitor.

Comment: I don't need to provide you any code, since it's not something which i have coded and been stuck into. It is simply a situation which is very easily handled in .NET, but i can't find a solution in php for that.

Comment: use union query to get all table data

Comment: You needed to provide a table structure in order to determine whether there is a common point between the tables. Use `union` keyword since there isn't any.

Answer (score 0):

Look into InnerJoin. That's how you make multiple selections at once - assuming you have a common data point

Comment: There is no common point. I simply want to concat 2 or more select statements and trying to get the result into an array of array..

Comment: What about defining in detail all fields?  SELECT a.a, a.b, z.a, z.b FROM c AS a, y AS z  - the AS is an extra you might not even need... this should work but I never attempted it on more then 2 tables...

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

```
$this->db->query('SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name1 UNION ALL SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name2');
```

**UNION ALL** This is the UNION keyword, and the optional ALL keyword. UNION indicates that the results of the SELECT statement that precedes UNION will be combined with the results of the SELECT statement that follows UNION.

When you use the ALL keyword, duplicate rows are not removed from the combined set that is produced by the union. This can dramatically improve the performance of the query, because Access does not have to check the results for duplicate rows. You should use the ALL keyword if any of the following conditions is true:

- You are certain that the select queries will not produce any
  duplicate rows.
- It does not matter if your results have duplicate rows.
- You want to see duplicate rows.

**EDITED**

After your edition and what I've got it from your question then this might be helpful. You need to loop that queries to get an array of `results` as

```
$tablename = array('name1','name2','name3','name4','name5','name6','name7');
$results = array();
foreach($tablename as $key => $value){
    $results[$key] = $this->db->query("select * from ".$value."")->result_array();
}
```

Comment: The Problem is that , all the tables have different schemas, so union can't be used in this case. I will update my question to stress on this fact.

Comment: Then do updation over your question that might be needful to understand in better way..

Comment: @ Narendra Sisodia I wanted to avoid this approach. My aim is to minimize the database hits, which a foreach doesn't do.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple select query in codigniter

```
 $this->db->select('t1.*, t2.*');
 $this->db->from('table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2');
 $query = $this->db->get();
 $row = $query->result_array();
 print_r($row);
```

Comment: Won't that result in their Cartesian product? i.e. if there are three rows in each table, you'll get nine rows back?

Comment: will this hit the database once or twice? will the records from different tables be available in different result sets? i doubt it.

Comment: this will hit the db once and get you all table result available in array

Comment: This will give me the cartesian product of the 2 tables. Not what i want

Comment: You've not replied to my key point, so downvoting, with apologies. If you believe this won't result as I have speculated, please explain why.

Comment: @halfer my query returns the Cartesian product of two table fro exm. if there is 6 record in one table and 14 record in other table it will return you 72 record.